# How to remove shadow behind popovers on iOS 9?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, popover, ios9

In iOS 8, popovers had no shadow. Now in iOS 9, there is a very heavy and far reaching shadow that can look less than desirable on pure white backgrounds. How can that shadow be removed, and instead add a thin light gray line around the popover? Or at least reduced or made lighter.

This occurs when showing action sheets, presenting a view controller using the `.Popover` `UIModalPresentationStyle`, and perhaps in other contexts.

Popover segue:
[image]

Action sheet:

```
UIActionSheet(title: "Title", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: "Destroy").showInView(sender as! UIView)
```

[image]

Comment: If you have a use case for why your popovers should look different from everyone else's, I suggest filing an enhancement request with Apple. The shadow effect is drawn by the UIPopoverPresentationController but you don't get any way to intervene or customize its behavior.

Comment: There is no API for what you want. Create your own "popover" class with no shadow if that's what you need.

Comment: @Joey, have you figure out anything, do not you think my answer is right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make your own custom popover background using `UIPopoverBackgroundView`

In the `initWithFrame` of your `UIPopoverBackgroundView` implementation, you can use a `[UIColor clearColor` for the drop shadow.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Strangely, the color seems to be the only property you can change. I tried also changing the other shadow properties like radius, opacity, etc to no avail

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 version of accepted answer.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)    
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```